# Error: missing : after property id?

Tags: javascript, json, coldfusion

I'm trying to solve the problem in JSON, for some reason I'm getting the error in this line of code:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id


jsObj[area-yearId [key]] = {100, 2500};
```

My original code looks like this:

```
var jsObj = {};
    <cfoutput query="myQuery">
       jsObj[building-term [key]] = {#myQuery.area#, #myQuery.yearId#};
       jsObj[building-term key].startdate = #myQuery.sDate#;
       jsObj[building-term key].enddate = #myQuery.eDate#;
    </cfoutput>
    alert(JSON.stringify(jsObj));
```

If anyone can help please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you declare it as an array or you add ids:

```
[100, 2500];

{id1: 100, id2: 2500};
```

Answer (score 0):

The {} in `jsObj[area-yearId [key]] = {100, 2500};` is interpreted as object literal, not a code block (terminology?). Object literals are in the form `{ id: property }`, hence the error message.